# How to Draw Arrowline in android.graphics.Path with correct configerations

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-shape

**What I have Tried:**

I'm trying to display the arrow line with following code

```
Path mArrowPath=new Paint();;
mArrowPath.rewind();
mArrowPath.moveTo(0, mHeight / 2);
mArrowPath.lineTo(mWidth / 2, 0);
mArrowPath.lineTo(mWidth, mHeight / 2);
mArrowPath.lineTo(mWidth * 3 / 4, mHeight / 2);
mArrowPath.lineTo(mWidth * 3 / 4, mHeight);
mArrowPath.lineTo(mWidth / 4, mHeight);
mArrowPath.lineTo(mWidth / 4, mHeight / 2);
mArrowPath.lineTo(0, mHeight / 2);

Shape pathshap = new PathShape(mArrowP,maxWidth,maxHeight);

ShapeDrawable shapeD = new ShapeDrawable(pathshap);

shapeD.draw(canvas); //display it in onDraw(Canvas canvas)
```

I have got the following result

[image]

**Problem:**

I'm not able draw the required expected result, I'm failed to understand/find  path configuration parameters for displaying following result!
I'm failed to increase the **length**, **width** size  of the arrow line.

**Expected result:**

[image]

any help will be grateful !

Comment: Have you tried replacing `mWidth` with `mHeight` and vice versa in your code?

Comment: Yes, I'm not good at graphics, I'm failed increase the length of the arrow tail. with specified configuration.

Comment: I can't use _canvas.drawPath(path, paint)_  used to draw the line like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713757/how-do-i-draw-an-arrowhead-in-android

Answer (score 1):

you can use canvas.rotate() method to rotate arrow

OR

```
Path mArrowPath=new Paint();;
mArrowPath.rewind();
mArrowPath.moveTo(mWidth , mHeight / 2);
mArrowPath.lineTo(mWidth / 2, mHeight );
mArrowPath.lineTo(mWidth / 2, mHeight* 3 / 4);
mArrowPath.lineTo(0, mHeight* 3 / 4);
mArrowPath.lineTo(0, mHeight/ 4);
mArrowPath.lineTo(mWidth / 2, mHeight/ 4);
mArrowPath.lineTo(mWidth / 2,0);
mArrowPath.lineTo(mWidth , mHeight / 2);
Shape pathshap = new PathShape(mArrowP,maxWidth,maxHeight);

ShapeDrawable shapeD = new ShapeDrawable(pathshap);

shapeD.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: In this case I cant use canvas since I'm Using ShapeDrawable , I can use _Matrix_ for any shape rotation, I'm looking for the rifgt config to path for changing the arrow tail lenth.

Comment: i think its problem with your coordinates, try drawing in papper.@LOG_TAG